# How to loop through multi dimensional array response from Ajax in Jquery?

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to get the quantity of raw materials along with the raw material id. I send recipe id and in response I am getting array like this

`[54,"Vanilla Cake Mix",2000] [126,"Water",1200] [1,"Refined Soyabean Oil",200]`

Where 54 is Raw Material ID,
Vanilla Cake Mix is Raw Material Name,
And 2000 is Quantity

How do I access each value of this?

My Jquery code is

```
      `$.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"api_consumption.php",
        data: "product_recipe_id="+product_recipe_id+"&quantity="+value,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(html)
        {
          //I want to access the values received in json array format.
        }
      });`
```

My PHP code is

```
$array = array($raw_material_id, $raw_material_name, $raw_material_quantity);
echo json_encode($array);
```

I tried the each loop but failed.

Sample Output:

When I comment this code `dataType: "json",`

and `alert(html)`, I get this

[Sample Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3QMJ.png)

Comment: Please, provide a sample output

Comment: I have edited with ss.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to `alert` the data, you can just simply convert the data:

```
 success: function(html)
   {
       let data = JSON.parse(html);
       alert(data);
   }
```

But I believe you will need it in a `textbox` or `dropdown`, that's when you can loop through each data.

```
 success: function(html)
   {
         let jsonData = JSON.parse(html);
         let data = '';
         $.each(jsonData, function(key, value){
             data+= '<option value="'+jsonData[key][0]+'">'+ jsonData[key][0] + 
             ' - '+ jsonData[key][1] +' - '+ jsonData[key][2]  +'</option>';
         });
         $('#dropdown-id').html(data);
   }
```